# How does mySQL save the new line formatting of text

Tags: mysql, laravel, textarea, line-breaks

When saving data from `<textarea>` elements into mySQL, the data stored in mySQL seems to save the format in which the data was entered.

***For example***

When the data entered is "Row 1, Row 2, Row 3", when you copy paste from the column that the data has been saved into, it will be displayed as "Row 1, Row 2, Row 3"

However, when the data entered is

"Row 1

Row 2

Row 3" when you copy paste from the column that the data has been saved into, it will be displayed in the format that you had entered the text in.

How does mySQL identify the presence of new line without any `</br>` or `\n` in the data?

Answer (score 0):

It does have a newline. The `\n` is present, it's just whitespace.

Check this out:

```
mysql> set @s = 'Row 1
    '> 
    '> Row 2
    '> 
    '> Row 3';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select hex(@s);
+----------------------------------------+
| hex(@s)                                |
+----------------------------------------+
| 526F7720310A0A526F7720320A0A526F772033 |
+----------------------------------------+
   R o w   1\n\n R o w   2\n\n R o w   3
```

The ASCII code for a newline is 0x0A in hexadecimal.